# Are SwingWorker threads isolated from each other, and are they a good fit for an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, swing, executorservice, swingworker, executionexception

I am attempting to execute SwingWorker's with an Executor. When I execute/submit these tasks with a thread pool size of 1, the tasks execute perfectly.

However when I execute the tasks with a thread pool size of bigger than 1 I get ExecutionException's encapsulating NullPointerException's and OutOfBoundsException's that I have seen. These exceptions do not occur when the tasks are run serially.

All tasks shared a common config file - I have now changed this so that they use their own config files. I was hoping that this would remove one area of tripping over thread unsafety.

Unfortunately I do not have access to the source code of the library I am calling asynchronously.

I really have two questions:

1). Do SwingWorker threads share resources? I'd assume that they do, and that my issue is due to a lack of thread safety in the library I am calling e.g. a singleton.

2). Can anyone comment further on the suitability of using SwingWorker with an ExecutorService? Do you have any horror stories? The reason I am using SwingWorker is that all this sits under a GUI and I would like to be able to display progress updates in the future. This is what has prevented me from just using guava's ListenableFuture instead, but if anyone has a good solution to progress updates I would be open to it.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your library is not thread safe.

Comment: never faces, everything (described here) is like as fog, one gust of wind and the sky is clear,  without your code, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value in local variables, demonstrated a.m. issue with thread pool

Comment: Stack traces and code samples would be quite helpful here.